# Where to store token dynamically in node js

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0

I'm building a web app that makes server-side calls to an external API. The external API uses OAuth2.0. I have the client_Id and client_Secret stored in server-side env variables. This particular API delivers an access token that never expires. What is the best practice for storing this token programmatically (as part of my OAuth2.0 flow), outside of adding a database to my project? Is an encrypted cookie a secure option?

I explored encrypted cookies and storing the token in the file system, but wanted to explore best practices here on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PER USER STORAGE**

It is common to use encrypted cookies for tokens that are user specific. This avoids needing to manage and secure your own backend token store.

**PER MACHINE STORAGE**

When the same token is used for all users, store the token in memory instead. This ensures the same ease of manageability.

In clustered setups, each instance of your web app will store a different instance of the token with the same privileges.

If an instance ever needs to refresh a token during user requests you can write code similar to this, if you need to synchronize the refresh operation:

```js
const newToken = await concurrencyHandler.run(refreshOperation);
```

The first incoming request can then make the token request, and all other incoming requests can wait for the same result, as in [this code of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/utilities/concurrentActionHandler.ts#L36).